# How to let the user to choose from Gallery or take picture option in Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera

I want to let the user to add a pic to the Cordova application and I would like to let the user to choose the pic from his albums or take a picture instantly. How do I provide such an option using Cordova.

Does Cordova provide such a feature out of the box or we have to write one? Please advice me how to proceed with the requirement.

Cheers!

Comment: [camera.getPicture()](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) where `Camera.sourceType` allows you to specify source as `CAMERA`, `PHOTOLIBRARY` or `SAVEDPHOTOALBUM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot @GenieWanted & @Sumn2u for your responses, special thanks to @GenieWanted for your time and extended support.

From the answer for the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852903/phonegap-give-user-option-of-picturesourcetype) I understand that there is no direct solution provided by Cordova to give the user an option to choose from multiple `Camera.PictureSourceType`. You have to pop a native/custom alert with option to choose from Gallery or Camera.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at their  [Camera](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) object? They have a clean documentation on the same. Another third party lib that you may want to look into:

https://github.com/Arcticus/Eirene/tree/master/Image%20Picker

Comment: Could you please guide me what exactly in the Cordova doc I could find it? Because, I tried all the possible Camera options but non of them worked. I'm testing it on Moto G with 4.4.2 can this be an issue? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Try running the full example that is given in the link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Comment: But before that you need to add <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature> in your config.xml

Comment: In the page, they have explained each function that is related with Camera object. Andha page la full details kuduthrukaanga..

Comment: This might give you some ideas: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO_59WXg33g

Comment: :Thanks for your prompt reply. As you suggested executed, the full sample on Android and iOS and I couldn't get the popup where I'm able to choose Gallery or Camera. When I clicked the first 2 buttons Capture Photo & Capture Editable Photo it directly opened the camera for me to take picture. When I clicked on the other 2 buttons From Photo Library & From Photo Album both these buttons opened the library directly for me. What I'm looking forward is when I click on the button I need a popup where the user could select take picture or load from gallery. Cordova has this feature?

Comment: This is achievable. What you have to do is, on a button click, you can show an alert with two options (buttons). Lets say button 1 as "Load Camera" and button 2 as "pick from photos". So, if the user presses button 1, execute the function "CapturePhoto() and for button 2, execute the function getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);

Comment: Thank you so much machi! Romba nandri!

Comment: Github link shows 404.

Answer (score 0):

you have to see the proper documentation of phonegap. you are using camera 
 you can go http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera for  camera API

and for the storage API you have to go 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
 for  storage API

By reading  this two and combining these two it will work . Further you can read the whole 
documentation